# PowerBI Desktop - Get currently Logged in User

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI Desktop, due to issues with database connection,  I had to login to PowerBI Desktop using my own different user-accounts (admin / non-admin / Mgmt-account), one of which worked i.e. allowed the database connection.

Question: is there a way to find out which account is currently logged in to the Power BI Desktop? (without having to log in-and-out again).

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make a measure like so:

```
User = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
```

And put it in a card?